# Javascript Object inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Is it possible to push data inside push? I need to get the value of COMPONENT NAME (see in my code) of set it in label

```
this.itemOfSelectedPDList.map((value, index) => {
  this.data2.push({
    label: value.product_info.product_name,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'OO',
        children:
         {
           label: [
             value.product_info.product_components.map((value) => {
               //console.log(value.component.component_name)
               ** I need to push all component name here**
             })
           ]
         }
      }
    ]
  })
```

Comment: If you're trying to `push` within a `push`, it sounds like a code-smell, and possibly an XY problem. Can you let us know what your initial array looks like, tell us what you're trying to accomplish, and we can start from there?

Comment: Add your input and expected output. Without that, it's impossible for anyone to tell what you're after.

Comment: Are you expecting to use the returned array of the first map? If you are just adding to data2, forEach would be cleaner

Comment: here's the output I expecting: data2: {
  label: product_name,
  children: [
    {
       label: 'OO',
       children: [
          {label: 'sample1'},
          {label: 'sample2'},
          {label: 'sample3'},
        ]
     }
  ]



}

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect your desired output. It was just a bit incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate the `label` property with an array of component names do:

Replace:

```
    children:
     {
       label: [
         value.product_info.product_components.map((value) => {
           //console.log(value.component.component_name)
           ** I need to push all component name here**
         })
       ]
     }
```

With:

```
    children:
         value.product_info.product_components.map((value) => { 
          return {label: value.component_name};
         })
```

```js
let arr = [ { product_info: { product_name: 'hi', product_components: [{component_name: 'c1'}, {component_name: 'c2'}] }}];
var data2 = [];

arr.map((value) => {
  data2.push({
    label: value.product_info.product_name,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'OO',
        children:
             value.product_info.product_components.map((value) => { 
              return {label: value.component_name};
             })
      }
    ]
  });
  
  })
  console.log(data2);
```